# Drawing a complex function in mathematica

Tags: computer-science

Is there a code that I can give mathematica to make it draw $e^{it}$  with $ 0\leqslant t\leqslant 2\pi $.Ofcourse I don't mean doing that by asking mathematica to draw a circle of center 0 and radius 1, I am trying to let $e^{it}$ and the domain of $t$ to be inputs.

Comment: pure mathematica question should go to [mathmatica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[t_]:=Exp[I t]
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[t]],Im[f[t]]},{t,0,2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.